# Logic for turning this pagination script into search pagination script

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I just spent sometime making the following tutorial work (I converted it to PDO instead of mysqli):
[PHP + MySQL Pagination tutorial](https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/create-pagination-with-php-and-mysql.html)
This is how it looks:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pagination</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

        if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
            $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
        } else {
            $pageno = 1;
        }
        $no_of_records_per_page = 10;
        $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;

        $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            die();
        }

        $total_pages_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$total_pages_sql);
        $total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
        $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
        $res_data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)){
            //here goes the data
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="?pageno=1">First</a></li>
        <li class="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
            <a href="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno - 1); } ?>">Prev</a>
        </li>
        <li class="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
            <a href="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno + 1); } ?>">Next</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="?pageno=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>">Last</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

But I encountered a problem: This script is paginating only for SQL query that has been predefined. But what if I want to have a "search" where the pagination script starts to work only after a user hits "search" and not with the pre-defined query of "select *"? Is it possible with the above script or I need to change it?

Answer (score 1):

Create HTML form, for example

```
<form id="form" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="<?= !empty($_GET['search']) ?
        htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']) : '' ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    <input type="hidden" id="page" name="page" value="<?= !empty($_GET['page']) ?
        intval($_GET['page']) : '' ?>">
    <!-- add another fields here -->
</form>
...
<a href="" class="page">1</a>
<a href="" class="page">2</a>
```

and at the top of the script add:

```
if (!empty($_GET['search']) { 
   // write SQL queries for pagination and other form processing logic here
}
```

To pass `page` parameter in URL, [include](https://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/jquery_get_started.asp) jQuery to your script and add the following code to the `head` section of the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.page').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#page').val($(this).html());
        $('#form').submit();
    });
});
```

This code blocks the default action for the link, set the page value to the form input with `#page` id and submits it.

Comment: I'm having troubles with this, because when I submit the form, then the search query overrides the `?pageno=` of the pagination script and I only get the search query at the address bar `?search=` and it messes everything up. I am not sure exactly where to put your code. I added the script in the original question so maybe you can help where exactly I should put that code

Comment: A few variables are undefined, and the pagination is simply broken. I am still trying to work on it though

Comment: perhaps a solution without jquery? Only php?

Comment: Using jQuery or just JavaScript here is a more correct and simple solution, @TTnote.